# i want to be able to echo all the element in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, session

I pretty newbie to php and javascript but more i am curious about PHP. I want to add elements into a empty array every time i add a new element trough a input form, and after that i want those elements to be displayed in to the browser .The code i use is this

```
  <form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="enter"><br><br>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['names']=array();
    $names=$_SESSION['names'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];


    array_push($names,$name);

    for($i=0;$i<count($names);$i++){
        echo $names[$i];
    }


};
```

How could i achieve to display every element inside the array that i add trough the input field in php?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: The question is how could i display every element that i add into an array from the form and displayed it in the browser?

Comment: Isn't your code already doing that?

Comment: No it overwrites the value every time i add a new value into the form ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite the value every time because you wipe out the array on every page load: `$_SESSION['names']=array();`. Instead check to see if that session variable exists (and is an array) *first* and, if it doesn't, *then* create it. Otherwise just append to that array.

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="enter"><br><br>
</form>


<?php
session_start();    

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['names']) || !is_array($_SESSION['names'])) {
        $_SESSION['names'] = array();
    }
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['names'][] = $name;

    $num_names = count($_SESSION['names']);
    for($i=0;$i<$num_names;$i++){
        echo $_SESSION['names'][$i];
    }
};
```

Comment: No John it still over writes the old values a keep adding different names and still it over writes the old values from the form

Comment: Did you remember to start your session?

Comment: John i am so sorry i forgot to start the session it was my mistake , indeed the code works very well , that"s what i asked to do . I want to thank you so much , i learned a lot from you code that was very helpful.THANK YOU SO MUCH John